# Task list remains empty on jBPM 6

Tags: jbpm

I created a basic business process with a start event, two user tasks and an end event. I also created two task forms with the markup editor. Is that normal that I can't see them in the Form definition left menu?

After deploying my process, I start a new instance form the Process definitions window. The jbpm-console shows me the process form on which I click on the start process button. Then, on the process model view, I can see that the current activitiy (red one) is the first user task, which seems logic. But now, how to fill my first user task form? The task list remains empty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you assign the tasks to the user that is currently logged in? or to the group that the user belong? 
In order to add the forms to each User Task you need to make sure that the Task Name property in the process designer is set to something different than an empty string. 
Hope it helps.

Comment: The task's actorId was missing! Thank you!

Comment: @Jocelyn can you provide a screenshot on how you set the actorId? I am still not getting anything on my list.

Comment: @ArchimedesTrajano Sorry, I don't work anymore on that project and I don't have access anymore to a jBPM instance.